# Can't login to TFS using TeamExplorer while it works using directly the webservice from IE

Tags: tfs

I've installed TFS 2008 sp1, full edition, on a windows 2008 server.

I can connect locally using either team explorer or IE

From a remote computer :

The TFS webservice works fine if I provide the good credentials on the following address :

http://192.168.1.239:8080/services/v1.0/ServerStatus.asmx?op=CheckAuthentication

However, Team Explorer keeps reporting a TF31002 error, and says that either :

- The Team Foundation Server name, port number or protocol is incorrect : Not the case because the WS works
- The Team Foundation Server is offline : Not the case for the same reason
- Password is expired or incorrect. : Visual Studio doesn't even ask for my credentials

Any ideas of what might be happening?
I thought about a potential version problem, and I installed the sp1 for visual studio 2008. It didn't solve anything.

Comment: Can you add what is being logged to the TFS server's eventlog?

Comment: Also, are you installing the Workgroup edition or the full edition?

Comment: full edition (I've updated my question accordingly)

Comment: I'll post the log when I'm back at work !

Answer (score 1):

Is is possible that you configured the server in VS to connect using HTTPS? If SSL isn't configured on your server, that would explain why the URL above works, but the URL Visual Studio is using (Same but with HTTPS) wouldn't work.

If not, can you install [fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/version.asp) (it's an HTTP traffic monitoring tool) on your workstation and watch the web traffic between VS and TFS? This will tell you exactly what web address VS is trying to reach, and might give you more insight into what's going on, so you can modify your question with the results.

Answer (score 0):

I wanna describe my expirience: we had TFS2010 that was accessible by VPN + SSL and got the same TF31002 error.

After long fighting we found out the problem: SSL used UNtrusted certificate and that was cause of the error!!

For resolving this problem should add SSL-certificate to local certificate store using for instance IE:  'Internet options -> Content -> Certificates -> 'select tab according to certificate' -> Import'. Hurray! Its working!